# Determine size of GeoTIFF header

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, numpy

Is there a way to find the size (in bytes) of the header information in a GeoTIFF file using Python? I am not trying to read the header (I know I can use `gdalinfo` for this) but rather to figure out what position I need to skip to in order to read the file as binary. This is because I am interested in testing numpy memory-mapped arrays for reading portions of an image from the disk. I would like to test this versus the gdal builtin `ReadAsArray()` method because I enjoy the flexibility of numpy indexing.

Comment: TIFF is a complex beastie. You will have a lot a work ahead of you to handle different interleaving, compression, tiling, tiff format, internal non-header data such as overviews and masks, multi-pages, etc.

Comment: There is nothing GIS specific in reading GeoTIFFs but I think that first you should read http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/corion.htm, then the offset to the first IFD, and find StripOffsets from there `This field is the only way for a reader to find the image data`. In general case you can't just jump to one offset value and start reading the data because strips may not be continuous. But StripOffsets should give a complete list of offsets for you.

Comment: Or you could `gdal_translate` to ENVI or EHdr format to output a flat binary file + sidecar header.

Comment: Use rasterio, it gives you numpy arrays: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/

Comment: @user30184 thanks for the tips & reference material, this looks very useful. I hadn't been able to find this sort of documentation so far but it might be exactly what I need.

Comment: @Luke thanks for the input, it could be that implementing this will end up being more trouble than it's worth. I hadn't considered the factor of compression, and didn't realize that TIFFs were ever saved with different interleave orders. I may end up just using the gdal  built-in methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [tifffile](https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile), which is a Python package to read and write image data from and to TIFF files.

```
import tifffile
import numpy as np

fname = 'my.tif'
tif = tifffile.TiffFile(fname)
page = tif.pages[0]  # first page
arr = page.asarray()  # we're done
```

So far, this is no different than either rasterio or GDAL.

To answer your question, you can get the byte offset and size from the `page.is_contiguous` property, then read it with regular numpy or any other tool that can read contiguous data:

```
offset, byte_count = page.is_contiguous
with open(fname, 'rb') as fp:
    fp.seek(offset)
    # if this is a 4-byte float file ...
    arr2 = np.fromfile(fp, dtype=np.float32, count=byte_count / 4)
arr2.shape = arr.shape
assert (arr2 == arr).all()
```

Comment: Thanks! In the end I think I may go with built-in gdal functions as I have just discovered the `gdal.Dataset.GetVirtualMemArray` method which seems to do exactly what I was ultimately hoping to do, & saves me the trouble of worrying about the internal file structure. But, it is good to know about the `tifffile` package & this does exactly what I asked for, so +1. In addition this may be very handy for anyone who has a specific need for this functionality.